# How do I combine three "select distinct" from same table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

For a search function, I want to return three types of results, so I query three times. It would probably be better to JOIN or UNION the queries into one, but how..

```
string sql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT area, CHARINDEX(@ss, area) FROM rgmaplocation WHERE area LIKE '%' + @ss + '%' ORDER BY CHARINDEX(@ss, area) ";
string sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT compound, CHARINDEX(@ss, compound) FROM rgmaplocation WHERE compound LIKE '%' + @ss + '%' ORDER BY CHARINDEX(@ss, compound) ";
string sql3 = "SELECT DISTINCT streetname, CHARINDEX(@ss, streetname) FROM rgmaplocation WHERE streetname LIKE '%' + @ss + '%' ORDER BY CHARINDEX(@ss, streetname)";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mikael Eriksson's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782885/how-do-i-combine-three-select-distinct-from-same-table/7783142#7783142) is good if you don't mind having area, compounds and streetname mixed up. If you want to keep them separate, here you go

```
WITH C(No,Loc, Idx) AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT 1,area, CHARINDEX('g', area) 
  FROM rgmaplocation 
  WHERE area LIKE '%g%' 
  UNION 
  SELECT DISTINCT 2,compound, CHARINDEX('g', compound) 
  FROM rgmaplocation 
  WHERE compound LIKE '%g%' 
  UNION 
  SELECT DISTINCT 3,streetname, CHARINDEX('g', streetname) 
  FROM rgmaplocation 
  WHERE streetname LIKE '%g%' 
)
SELECT No,Loc, Idx
FROM C
ORDER BY No,Idx
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this to union the result and do order by the charindex expression.

```
;WITH C(Loc, Idx) AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT area, CHARINDEX('g', area) 
  FROM rgmaplocation 
  WHERE area LIKE '%g%' 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT compound, CHARINDEX('g', compound) 
  FROM rgmaplocation 
  WHERE compound LIKE '%g%' 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT streetname, CHARINDEX('g', streetname) 
  FROM rgmaplocation 
  WHERE streetname LIKE '%g%' 
)
SELECT Loc, Idx
FROM C
ORDER BY Idx
```

Comment: or `UNION ALL`, as the three result sets are probably different anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Using [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx), as you said it should look like:

```
string sqlAll = string.Format( "{0} UNION {1} UNION {2}", sql1, sql2, sql3 );
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT area, CHARINDEX('g', area) FROM rgmaplocation WHERE area LIKE '%g%' ORDER BY CHARINDEX('g', area) UNION SELECT DISTINCT compound, CHARINDEX('g', compound) FROM rgmaplocation WHERE compound LIKE '%g%' ORDER BY CHARINDEX('g', compound) UNION SELECT DISTINCT streetname, CHARINDEX('g', streetname) FROM rgmaplocation WHERE streetname LIKE '%g%' ORDER BY CHARINDEX('g', streetname)

it says 

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'

Comment: @Jesper I've just tested my suggestion with your initial 3 SQL statements in SSMS. I do not get any errors (beside that I do not have the variable `@ss` declared, of course).

Comment: it keeps giving the error here. I have added your line exactly as written here.

Comment: @Jesper - `order by` in a union query is only valid for the entire expression. You can not have one order by for each part.